# How to upload file extension (*.xls or *.xlsx)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to upload file excel with extension *.xls or *.xlsx... But i can only upload with extension *.xls... 
This's my code...

```
                include APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';                
                $excelreader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
                $loadexcel = $excelreader->load('assets/excel/'.$name);
                $sheet = $loadexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true ,true);
```

How i can upload with extension *.xls or extension *.xlsx?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail?

Comment: Is your problem trying to upload files with an extension of `xlsx` or is your problem trying to read files with an extension of `xlsx`? If it's the uploading that is the problem you need to [edit] your question and include the code that handles file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will save the file in a specified directry in xlsx file

```
include APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';                
$excelreader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$loadexcel = $excelreader->load('assets/excel/'.$name);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($loadexcel, 'Excel2007');
$loadexcel->save('test.xlsx');
```